# How do fairy lights work when they have a lot of LEDs in series?

Tags: led

A single typical diode has 0.6V drop across it. I came across something called fairy lights. It is a whole lot of LED lights that are connected along a long wire and I expect that they are all in series. They are powered from 2 AA batteries.

How can 2 AA batteries power so many LEDs since 2 AA batteries only give 3V.

Comment: `they are all in series` ... how do you know this?

Comment: By the way, "a typical diode" with a forward voltage of 0.6 V (rather unusual, Schottky is much lower, and pn silicon typically more like 0.7 V) is not an LED. Following your nickname, you should realize that 0.6 V is not a bandgap large enough for direct emission of visible photons! Mind the \$\hbar\$!

Answer (score 4):

Many of these fairy lights are NOT connected in series, but in parallel. The white (actually blue, with a phosphor) LED forward bias is about 3.1V, which as a happy accident matches roughly what a pair of AA batteries provides.

The battery pack may have a small series resistor (a few ohms), or it may not.

Comment: The fairy lights that I have are wired in parallel.

Comment: But if we need 100 LEDs in parallel, that would be a lot of wires, I don't see so many wires.

Comment: You only need two wires - the LEDs connect across them, like rungs on a ladder

Answer (score 1):

The answer that fairy lights are connected ladder like in series is correct.  Most of the ones I bought require 5V or 12V DC  Some I bought at my local Goodwill surplus store are battery operated.  Anything with more than 20 LEDs uses 3 AA batteries. If you pry the battery case apart you will find a resistor between the batteries and the on/off switch.  It may be so small you can't really tell the value unless it is printed on the circuit board.  I use these fairy lights in Christmas displays so battery operated lights are not cost effective since I want everything to turn off at once from a single power source. Anything that runs on 4.5V can be wired to a 5V DC converter but you might have to use a slightly higher value resistor in place of the one inside the battery pack. So far none that I tried burned out when connected to a 5V converter used for charging a cell phone in place of the 3 batteries with no change to the resistor.

If you wish to use 12V or just part of longer light string it is simpler to use a buck module to replace the battery case and gradually increase the voltage from zero to where the light string is bright enough but not so bright as to destroy the LEDs.  If you buy them directly from China on eBay they are as cheap as a dollar each https://www.ebay.com/itm/314478104995  You can do the same with any parallel circuit of 5mm LEDs as long as they all have the same forward voltage. Can't mix colors with different forward voltages on a single buck module but you can use resistors instead.

Most commercial Christmas light strings are series circuits with the lights in groups of 25 LEDs so they work on 120V AC.  If you buy a 100 (5mm) LED light string it will have four separate groups of 25 lights.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a series connected set of leds, a boost converter can be used to drive them. Though for large strings (e.g. 10 white leds drop around 35 volts), other topologies with a transformer would be more efficient.

Comment: I thought that there would a current source in the device. But then I don't know how that would work as well with a large number of LEDs in series.